# Динамический массив (С++)

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Разве `arrWithDigits`-это массив? Это же переменная, хранящая его адрес.Почему мы работаем с указателем как с массивом в этой строчке `arrWithDigits[i] = i + 1;`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int sizeOfArray = 0;

    cout << "Чтобы создать массив чисел, введите его размер: ";
    cin >> sizeOfArray;

    int* arrWithDigits = new int [sizeOfArray]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        arrWithDigits[i] = i + 1;
        cout << arrWithDigits[i] << " ";
    }   
    cout << endl;

    delete [] arrWithDigits;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В языках C и C++ встроенный оператор `[]` всегда работает с *указателями и только с указателями*. (Не совсем верно, см. поправку ниже).

Когда вы применяете встроенный оператор `[]` к объекту типа "массив", этот объект сначала незримо преобразуется к типу "указатель" (указывающий на начало массива), а затем уже к этому указателю применяется оператор `[]`.

Например, когда вы пишете

```
int a[10];
a[5] = 42;
```

язык С на самом деле внутренне интерпретирует этот код как

```
int a[10];
int *ptr = (int *) a; /* `ptr` указывает на начало `a` в памяти */
ptr[5] = 42;
```

а это, по определению оператора `[]` через операторы `+` и `*`, интерпретируется как

```
int a[10];
int *ptr = (int *) a; /* `ptr` указывает на начало `a` в памяти */
*(ptr + 5) = 42;
```

В вашем случае оператор `[]` сразу применен к указателю, то есть никаких незримых преобразований просто не нужно. С этой точки зрения можно даже утверждать, что использование оператора `[]` является, в некотором смысле, более *естественным*, чем использование этого оператора с массивами.

---

С педантичной точки зрения, вышесказанное справедливо только для С. В С++ оператор `[]` *сначала* преобразуется в эквивалентную форму через операторы `+` и `*`, а только *затем* в контексте оператора `+` происходит преобразование массива к указателю. То есть в С++ (в отличие от С) мой пример проинтерпретируется как

```
int a[10];
*(a + 5) = 42;
```

а это уже, в свою очередь, интерпретируется как

```
int a[10];
int *ptr = (int *) a; /* `ptr` указывает на начало `a` в памяти */
*(ptr + 5) = 42;
```

Конечный итог, как видите, один и тот же, но абстрактная семантика несколько отличается.

(Спасибо @Croessmah за комментарий.)

Comment: `A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type. The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ]`  
Сначала оно преобразуется в *((a) + (5)), а уже затем преобразуется в указатель.

Comment: @Croessmah: Да, согласно процитированному, в С++ есть такая тонкость.

Answer (score 5):

Запись `pointer[index]` это тоже самое, что и `*(pointer + index)`, только удобнее.
Поэтому, например, *можно (но не нужно)* писать и так: `index[pointer]`, это преобразуется в `*(index + pointer)`, то есть разницы не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Для указателя `type* ptr` запись

```
*(ptr+i)
```

и

```
ptr[i]
```

по сути эквивалентны.

Так что `arrWithDigits` - да, массив, просто в выделенном оператором `new` месте в памяти.

Comment: Тоесть если мы пишем *(arrWithDigits+1) = число, то мы присваиваем второму элементу массива значение? (arrWithDigits+1)- это адрес на элемент массива с индексом 1?

Comment: arrWithDigits - указатель. И, имхо, именно в этом вопрос ТС. Почему оно работает для указателя.

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich ну да.

Comment: Artem Aleksandrovich  arrWithDigits это не массив, а указатель на начало массива.  Имя массива отличается тем, что она является именем константного указателья... Любому указателью можно прибавить целое n...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: В реальности не существует никакого "константного указателья". Такое упрощение ("Имя массива является именем константного указателя") применяется в учебной литературе, но лучше от него постепенно избавляться. Имя массива - это имя монолитного объекта типа "массив".

Comment: Да, но обьяснять так легче

Comment: AnT,  а вам лучше постепенно избавляться  отвечать мне или оценивать мои ответы. Конкретно  в ваших комментариях я не нуждаюсь

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, как лучше/легче/правильнее объяснять — вопрос спорный. Я, например, ничего не знаю об авторе данного вопроса и не могу судить об уровне его познаний в языках программирования в общем и C++ в частности. Возможно, человек только осваивает основы и хочет увидеть объяснение попроще, но быть может он совсем не новичок, и хочет разобраться в тонкостях работы оператора `[]`, и потому хочет увидеть максимально подробный ответ. В любом случае, тот факт, что имя массива — это не указатель, а самостоятельная сущность, довольно важен. А вообще, какой-то Вы агрессивный ;)

Comment: да, но причем тут вы и где моя агрессивность я не понел. Наверное я по ошибке вам отправил, а не автору вопроса. Я  не агрессивный, а вот   вы ведать быстро обижаетесь